# How to "revive" stdin after input of wrong type

Tags: c, exception, stdin

The code below works like expected if the user enters only integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int input1, input2;
    int error;

    error = scanf("%d", &input1);
    if( !error)
        printf("Error: Your input was wrong\n");
    else
        printf("Your input was: %d\n", input1);

    error = scanf("%d", &input2);
    if( !error)
        printf("Error: Your input was wrong");
    else
        printf("Your input was: %d\n", input2);

}
```

However if the user types in `abcd` at the first prompt, the program prints out:

```
Error: Your input was wrong
Error: Your input was wrong
```

skipping the second `scanf()`
How can I "revive" `stdin` once an input has failed, so that it can be reused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!error){
    printf("Error: Your input was wrong\n");
    scanf("%*[^\n]");
} else
    printf("Your input was: %d\n", input1);
```

Comment: This one works. Can you explain to me how it works and where it is documented please?

Comment: @Machtl `"%*[^n]"` It will consume the input of the newline up. second scanf  to the same failure  because input remaining.